# Restore wallet in Exodus using JSON file

Tags: wallets, import

I've a wallet file in the JSON format with *address*, *cipher*, *ciphertext*, *salt*, etc (version 3).

How can I restore it into Exodus wallet?

In *Developer* menu I can only see *Restore from 12-word phrase...*.

I'm using Exodus desktop app (v1.51.0) on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON file is actually a keystore file - it contains your encrypted private key. As far as I know Exodus does not support importing Ethereum private keys. You can use [MyCrypto offline](https://download.mycrypto.com/) to access your wallet using the keystore file.

Then simply send the funds to a new address created in Exodus. Make sure to backup the 12 word mnemonic phrase.